# Will AD calls automatically switch to LDAPS if unsigned LDAP on port 389 is disabled?

Tags: active-directory

Does anyone know if calls to create a new PrincipalContext will automatically switch to LDAPS from LDAP when Microsoft releases its AD security update in March?  We have created a VB.Net security library for our corporate applications that instantiates the object like below, with no explicit reference to port 636 in the domain string.  I have tested the library with Wireshark running, and I only see unsigned LDAP (port 389) traffic, but we have both ports enabled, so I don't know if it will automatically switch to LDAPS.

```
Return New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my.corp.domain", container, Config.ADUser, Config.ADPass)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not switch to LDAPS if normal LDAP doesn't work. You have to specify LDAPS explicitly by passing the LDAPS port as part of the domain name: `"my.corp.domain:636"`

That said, I haven't read anything to suggest that Microsoft will be disabling access to the LDAP port entirely. From what I understand, the issue is only with how the requests are authenticated. Port 389 will continue to function.

Actually, the change in March won't change anything at all. You can read more about it [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-march-update/ba-p/921536#), which says:

> March 2020 update will only add some new functionalities and make no changes, giving Customers more time to fix issues.